# New Ubuntu Server 22.04 install freezing on boot due to Nouveau/NVIDIA driver issues

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 22.04, nouveau

I'm trying to do a clean install of Ubuntu Server 22.04 into a host that has 2 NVIDIA A6000 GPUs. My goal is to install the NVIDIA proprietary drivers and CUDA.

However, while the clean installation works fine, the moment I install the official NVIDIA drivers or disable the Nouveau driver it freezes on boot just before the point where it would normally change the screen resolution as it boots up, still showing more text. (This is not Ubuntu Desktop, so there's no UI starting, just a console login.)

To be more specific:

- Nouveau enabled, no NVIDIA driver: works
- Nouveau disabled, no NVIDIA driver: freezes
- Nouveau enabled, NVIDIA driver: freezes
- Nouveau disabled, NVIDIA driver: freezes

I've also tried using different versions of the NVIDIA server driver (525, 515...) as well as the official sh installer with no change. Secure boot is also disabled from the BIOS.

Also, when I manually install the NVIDIA proprietary driver and before rebooting, I can see my GPUs correctly using nvidia-smi. Yet the moment I reboot it freezes always in the same point. Doesn't matter how much I wait for it to continue. Checking the system journal didn't seem to give any useful clues either.

Any suggestions about what else I could try?

Comment: Are you sure the computer "freezes"?  If you are at the console what happens when you hit `Ctrl-Alt-F1`?  When you install graphics drivers and do not install graphical applications the system will boot into `graphical.target` and the console will show a blank black screen.

Comment: The system does not respond to Ctrl-Alt-F1 (or any other F keys). 

Furthermore, the server has an openssh server installed, and no matter how long you wait it doesn't respond either. Or even to pings.

Answer (score 1):

Found a way to avoid the freezes by adding nomodeset to grub.

[How do I set 'nomodeset' after I've already installed Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu)

Comment: This worked for me. I booted into recovery mode (under "Advanced Options for Ubuntu", navigated to `/etc/default` and edited the grub config options with `nano grub`. Added `nomodeset` so that `"quiet splash"` becomes `"quiet splash nomodeset"`